# Trouble installing wxWebConnect on Windows

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I've been trying for the past week to install version 1.2 of wxWebConnect in a Windows environment using MinGW but am stuck because, as far as I can tell, a file called top.mak is not included in the source code provided. I realize that this question might be better answered on their forums, but unfortunately their forums aren't allowing new users to register at the moment.

I already have wxWidgets 2.8.12 installed and have downloaded the wxWebConnect 1.2 source code and extracted it. I switch to the wxwebconnect-1.2/webconnect directory within MinGW and type make and get the error:

```
Makefile:12: /Makefiles/top.mak: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/Makefiles/top.mak'. Stop.
```

I've read that several others have had similar problems and were able to find a work around, but I can't seem to figure it out myself. Has anyone managed to get wxWebConnect working. I'd prefer to use MinGW on Windows but if anyone has got this working using Microsoft Visual or gcc  on linux, I've failed every method I've tried so far unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use wxWebConnect, it's a really bad choice by now. Get wxWidgets 2.9.4 or the upcoming 2.9.5 and use [wxWebView](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_web_view.html) included in it.

Comment: Wow thanks, that looks like it should fit what I need it for!